# Get current proxy in PhantomJS?

Tags: proxy, phantomjs

I'm starting many PhantomJS instances at the same time and therefore I do it by setting the proxy as a startup command:

```
phantomjs script.js --proxy=123.44.55.6:1234
phantomjs script.js --proxy=232.44.55.6:1234
phantomjs script.js --proxy=555.44.55.6:1234
etc
```

Everything works fine, but is there a way to print the current proxy that is in use to the console?

I'm looking to add something like this to the script:

```
console.log(getCurrentProxy);
```

I could make a function that gets the current IP from whatsmyip.org but that won't work when a proxy is dead and can't access internet.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't see the proxy that you set, because why would you, you've set it yourself. There is an undocumented `phantom.setProxy()` function, but there is no such equivalent to get the proxy settings. You will have to continue with trial and error. You can also edit the PhantomJS source code and re-compile it yourself in order to add such a function.

You have a problem with the order of the options. PhantomJS scripts may accept commandline options themselves through `system.args`. This means that you're passing the proxy option to the script and not PhantomJS itself.

Change

```
phantomjs script.js --proxy=123.44.55.6:1234
```

to

```
phantomjs --proxy=123.44.55.6:1234 script.js
```

Comment: The order of the options is not the issue here. I could type **script.js** after the proxy, sure, but it has nothing to do with my problem... I can't see the proxy that I have set, but why would I? Well, maybe I would like to see it for troubleshooting?!

Comment: As I said, it's not possible. Since PhantomJS is open-source, you can edit it and compile it yourself to get this information.